# Qt C++ Graphics View отрисовка в реальном времени

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

Я новичок в Qt, и хочу рисовать что-либо в Graphics View в реальном времени. Допустим, я хочу каждую секунду менять цвет фона. Я знаю, что с Graphics View можно работать с помощью функций по типу mousePressEvent, которые заданы заранее. Я ищу что-то наподобие функции update(), которая бы вызывалась каждый кадр, и в которой можно было бы прописать отрисовку графики в том числе, но я не смог найти подобное в интернете.

Comment: Вы пробовали писать код, или рассуждаете теоретически?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver, пробовал, написал часть (обработка кнопок и другой интерфейс), но именно с Graphics View проблемы, т.к. не могу найти, как реализовать то, что описано выше

Comment: QGraphicsView::update не делает того, что вам нужно?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver, QGraphicsView::update я не нашёл, есть только QGraphicsScene::update, но это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Мне необходима функция которая бы вызывалась каждый кадр и которую можно было бы написать под себя. Если, например, написать бесконечный цикл с отрисовкой в main() или MainWindow(), то программа попросту зависнет. Как пример, если вы знакомы с Unity или Unreal, то там есть функции update(), написав которые, можно задать код, который будет выполняться каждый кадр. Мне нужно что-то подобное, но в Qt. (Надеюсь понятно объяснил)

Comment: То есть мне нужна не функция, которая выведет изменения на экран, а которая эти изменения обработает и совершит, и будет делать это каждый кадр, "параллельно" с остальным кодом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заведи таймер и по таймеру обновляй фон:

```
...
    _view = new QGraphicsView;
    _view->setScene(new QGraphicsScene);
...
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer;
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::onTimeout);

    timer->start(1000); // 1 сек.
...

void MainWindow::onTimeout()
{
   _view->scene()->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt::black));
}
```